# How to deploy aspnet core web api and aspnet webapi on single app service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I have an aspnet core web api project which I can deploy through publish wizard to Azure App service. But later on I developed on normal aspnet web api (MVC 5 on .Net framework 4.6) because of the certain classes not available in dotnet core.

Now I want to deploy both them on same App service instance. Can I do that? will aspnet publish overwrite earlier aspnetcore publish when done to the same App service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One web application per App Service. You can have several App Services running on the same App Service Plan, though.

Think of the App Service granularity like a web site and app pool pair within the IIS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans

Comment: Just adding a bit of information: The App Service Plan determines the "performance" and the cost of the App Service. When multiple App Services share the same App Service Plan the cost does not increase but they will have to share the allocated compute resources.

Comment: Great! both of you answered my question and fear of costing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible through virtual applications under the App Service. I have a test setup now running, where the root application and the /api virtual applications are running .NET Framework 4.6 Web and WebAPI respectively, and the /api-dw is running a simple "hello world" version of a .NET Core Web API. Both work flawlessly. A full blown .NET Core App with database connections etc. is still to be tested, but looks promising!
[image]